# Why is MySQL shutting down even after I reinstalled XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

So the thing is, that I've been using XAMPP for pretty much since I've been coding php.

I have this issue where after I start MySQL it just shuts down right after with the following error message:

```
16:06:46  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
16:06:46  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
16:06:48  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
16:06:48  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
16:06:48  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:06:48  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:06:48  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:06:48  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:06:48  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
16:06:48  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I went on vacation for a week and before that it had no problems. After coming back and starting it, it didn't work.

I reinstalled XAMPP 5 times, even with fresh databases. Yesterday it finally started, but now it won't start again. What should I do?

I tried copying the backup folder, reinstalling (5 times), starting it with admin privileges, checking if the port is used, changing the port.
None of these worked for me.

Here is the mysql_error.log file:

```
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xmapp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xmapp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 344205; transaction id 318
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xmapp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-08-22 16:06:46 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-08-22 16:06:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked *16:06:48  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,* or * improper privileges,*

Comment: Use Windows Task Manager (ctrl+alt+delete) and check Services to ensure MYSQL is Stopped before starting.